# compile changed cpp files in visual studio (2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In a headless moment, i have clicked some buttons in visual studio, and now i can't compile only the changed .cpp or .cc files on startup my application. 
So i have to rebuild the hole project or touch a .h file. which is used by the changed .cpp file.

Does anybody know, where i can recover the original options, where also single changed cpp files will be compiled on startup?

On my notebook, the cpp files, which are out of date, will be compiled, so this is not an project specific option :-(.

Comment: Do you want the IDE to build only the changed files, or do you want it to build automatically when a file is changed?

Comment: I want the IDE to build only changed files (on start of the application).

Answer (score 0):

In the C/C++ Code Generation options, set "Enable Minimal Rebuild" and in Linker General options, set "Enable Incremental Linking".

Answer (score -1):

Tools -> Options

Project and Solutions -> Build and Run

Check out the state of the checkbox "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run": is the *.cpp file in question in the startup project or its dependency?

Check out the dropbox "On Run, when projects are out of date:"; set it to "Always build"?

Comment: The cpp file is part of the startup project.